# How can I "drive" in Android simulated phones when using Maps?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, geolocation, expo

I am working on a React Native app where I am trying to make some changes in my app depending on WHERE the current position is. I am using Android Studio's simulated phone in a Windows 10 machine. I know in IOS you have this feature called "Freeway drive" where it runs a simulation of me "driving" to my destination. And as the blue dot moves, my app modifies accordingly. I need this functionality in my app.

Could not find this answer anywhere so I spent hours researching and decided to write what I got here. Hopefully this post will save valuable time for any developer who faces the same issue as I did.

Answer (score 1):

you can "drive" in Android Studio simulated phones.

Open Android simulated phone > click the 3 dots > Click Location > click "Routes" tab > then just like Google maps, put the address or click on any part of the map as the destination > click "Play Route". it will be VERY slow so make sure you select "Speed X5" as well.

Here are some visual aids:

click the 3 dots on the right

[image: click the 3 dots on the right]

Then:
Location > Routes > choose destination > Play Route > Speed X5
[image: Location settings]